# How to populate SavedStateHandle with navigation arguments in instrumentation test using Hilt and Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation, dagger-hilt

I'm using a combination of Compose, Navigation, ViewModel and Hilt with `SavedStateHandle` to access nav arguments within the ViewModel. Everything works well together, however I've run into an issue when it comes to instrumentation testing.

Say I have a ViewModel:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    application: Application,
    ...
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val id = savedStateHandle.require<Long>("myId")
    ...
}
```

A Composable representing a screen that uses the ViewModel:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    ...
}
```

An instrumentation test that renders the composable using Hilt to provide the ViewModel and all of its dependencies:

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidTest
class MyTest {

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule by lazy { HiltAndroidRule(this) }

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val test by lazy { createAndroidComposeRule<TestActivity>() }

    @Test
    fun shouldRenderScreen() {
        test.setContent { MyScreen() }
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run this test the application will crash on `savedStateHandle.require<Long>("myId")` as `myId` doesn't exist. I have not been able to find a way to access or override the `SavedStateHandle` from the test code.

In the application `MyScreen` is wrapped in a `NavHost`, which enables me to access the nav arguments in the `SavedStateHandle`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyApp(
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = "home",
) {
    ...
    MyTheme {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = startDestination,
        ) {
            ...
            composable(
               "route/{myId}", arguments = listOf(
                    navArgument("myId") { type = NavType.LongType }
                )
            ) {
                MyScreen()
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now I realise that when setting the content in the test I can instantiate my own ViewModel with a `SavedStateHandle` and pass that into the screen, however I have a lot of dependencies that are provided by Hilt so that will require a lot of boilerplate.

I've tried using `@BindValue` to provide a `SavedStateHandle` in the test but this results in a duplicate binding error. I've tried `@Inject`ing the `SavedStateHandle` in the test but the dependency isn't found.

Lastly, I've abandoned the design of testing a single screen composable, instead setting the test content to `MyApp` passing `startDestination="route/1"`. This is less ideal as there's other code in this composable that I do not want to test. However, this surprisingly had the same issue of the argument not found in the `SavedStateHandle` in the `ViewModel`.

So is there an easy way to populate the Hilt-provided `SavedStateHandle` with nav arguments in the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SavedStateHandle` populates its arguments from the arguments of the `ViewModelStoreOwner` that the ViewModel is associated with - when inside your NavHost, that is the individual destination (that's why a route with `"route/{myId}"` fills in the `myId` argument - it would not work if your route is `"route/1"` since that does not include any argument).

When you don't have a `NavHost` in your test, the arguments it is pulling from is from the Activity itself - through the `extras` on the Activity's `intent`.

Therefore you can set the arguments on the Activity before you call `setContent` so that they are available when `hiltViewModel()` is called:

```
@Test
fun shouldRenderScreen() {
    // Set the extra manually on the Activity's Intent
    test.activity.intent.putExtra("myInt", 0L)

    test.setContent { MyScreen() }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's perfect for my use case, thanks a lot!